# In Redis, how to get the higest scores across multiple sorted sets?

Tags: redis

Let's say I have multiple sorted sets:

```
 zset1
 zset2
 zset3
```

Here is the data for all the sets:

```
zset1
-----
A:1
B:22
C:4
D:555

zset2
-----
N:14
O:15
P:16
D:2750

zset3
-----
D:333
Y:0
Z:1
```

This is the kind of result I want. Which zsets contain the highest value key pairs. And what are those key-pairs ?

```
Results
-------
zset2:D:2750
zset1:D:555
zset3:D:333
zset1:B:22
...
```

I looked into using ZINTERSTORE however it doesn't appear to be able to get say only the top 100 highest scores across multiple zsets. I have hundreds maybe thousands of zsets, if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you shouldn't expect to implement this thinking it like a *query* but you should store this data when you update your sorted sets.

Whenever you add or remove an item to your sorted sets, you need to update the *top items sorted set* adding, updating or dropping elements.

For example, when you add the element `A` in `zset1` you should add to `results` sorted set the element `zset1:A` with its corresponding score. And so on.

In Redis and most NoSQL solutions you should think your approach creating indexes in real time rather than like it would be with relational databases, where you throw the data and using complex SQL queries you can implement practically any requirement.

Comment: That is a good point on nosql/perspective. One caveat with my situation. I am not storing a value such as '555'. I am actually using `ZINCRBY` and incrementing the values one by one, so it's `ZINCRYBY` is called 555 times. There are many keys in each zset, most of them have such low scores, I don't want to know about them. I suppose I would have to make an additional redis command to update a single zset that tracks all the top scores across all zsets. Or, alternatively, I could have a script to periodically compute this (instead of keeping it up-to-date on the original inserting client).

Comment: @Zombies Yeah, you can turn this into a background process. You can also use a message queue / service bus and enqueue writes and attend them directly using an async service. I belive that this is the best bet possible and it's very simple to implement rather than using a background process.

Comment: @Zombies BTW, are you using `MULTI` commands? I mean, you should issue these `zincrby` in a single trip and you'll gain some perf

Comment: Well no, I'm not. The reason I haven't considered batching it is because I am reading from twitter streaming API. So the throughput/reading wouldn't increase basically. Although, just to reduce the CPU usage on the box overall, I think batching it would be a good idea. It's more green after all :)

Comment: @Zombies Well it has another advantage: `multi` commands are atomic. If some command in the middle fails during its execution in Redis, all changes will be discarded